# How to copy the anchor text and replace the href with using PHP

Tags: php

Hello so i have about 1000 link with anchor text formated like this

```
<a href="1_1_3.html" >my anchor text1</a>
<a href="1_4_8.html" >my anchor text2</a>
```

.... etc

i want to replace all the href link with their own anchor text and add .php at the end of the url

result must be like this :

```
<a href="my anchor text1.php" >my anchor text1</a>
<a href="my anchor text2.php" >my anchor text2</a>
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourhtml);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
   $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
   .... manipulate the href
   $a->setAttribute('href', $href);
}

$newhtml = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<a href="1_1_3.html" >my anchor text1</a>
<a href="1_4_8.html" >my anchor text2</a>';

$string = preg_replace('#<a href="(.*?)" >(.*?)</a>#is', '<a href="\\2.php" >\\2</a>', $string);

echo $string;
```

Result:

```
<a href="my anchor text1.php" >my anchor text1</a>
<a href="my anchor text2.php" >my anchor text2</a>
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/k9NOc

Comment: This will fail if the links aren't formatted _exactly_ as they are in the OP's example. Something as simple as `<a href="1_1_3.html">` will not to match.

Comment: This is an important caveat. If the OP (or anyone else) should try to apply this method to a set of links with even the slightest deviation from the specified format, it won't work. Parsing the HTML with DOMDocument alleviates this problem because it doesn't rely on a specific format.